# Почему сайты не доступны по ip адресу?

Tags: url, ip, dns, браузер, домен

Почему, если вбить в поисковую строку браузера ip-адрес сайта вместо url он будет не доступен? Если я не ошибаюсь, браузер не откроет сайт по ip-адресу, даже если у сайта ip выделенный.

Comment: от чего такие выводы? вполне себе откроет если на одном айпи один сайт. доменное имя ни что иное как заменитель айпи адреса - ведь гораздо проще запомнить site.com чем 78.147.78.514

Comment: т.е. любой сайт можно открыть по ip-адресу? можете привести пример?

Comment: да пожалуйста http://78.46.72.113/ нет не любой. только тот который один на айпи адресе.

Comment: о чудо) а почему yandex и google не доступны по ip-адресу?

Comment: потому что у таких сайтов куча серверов и куча айпи

Comment: так наверняка все они отдельные (более одного ip на один сайт)? по идее наоборот должны с нескольких ip открывать сайт?

Comment: у меня открывается 64.233.161.101 тут я не подскажу т.к не использовал подобное

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это зависит от настроек сервера и вида веб-сервера. Обычно, если специально ничего не делать, и сайт только один на сервере, то он будет открываться и по IP адресу. Несложно сделать так, чтобы для неизвестных доменов, и для запросов без заголовка `Host`, откры­вался ка­кой-то специально предназначенный сайт с одной страницей с объяснениями.

Например, в случае nginx такой специальный сайт [должен быть помечен](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html) параметром `default_server`.

Если мы говорим о каком-то массовом виртуальном хостинге, то обычная практика делать имен­но так, то есть ограничивая доступ к серверу по IP. Никто не хочет выслушивать жалобы от недо­вольного клиента, сайт которого, по случаю оказавшийся первым в списке, откры­ва­ется при вво­де в адресную строку какого-то другого домена, который по любой причине ука­зывает на IP сервера. Владелец того другого домена тоже не будет рад такому развитию событий.

Если ваш сайт работает по HTTPS, то одной настройки сервера будет недостаточно. Нужно будет [получить SSL сертификат](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2017/free-ssl-from-letsencrypt/) и для домена, и для IP адреса. Последнее не всегда возможно.